# Query custom attributes from g-suite with go

Tags: go, google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api

I would like to make a user query from my G-Suite users about the custom attributes set up on them.

I started from the [admin-sdk golang quickstart](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/quickstart/go) to use "FULL" projection and failed to query the custom attributes of the user.
For example it would be fine to query the standard attributes like phone or employee ID.

My custom attribute exists in the Category:Groups, Custom fields:group

```
        r, err := srv.Users.List().Projection("FULL").Customer("my_customer"). //MaxResults(20).
            OrderBy("email").Do()
    if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Unable to retrieve users in domain: %v", err)
    }

    if len(r.Users) == 0 {
            fmt.Print("No users found.\n")
    } else {
            fmt.Print("Users:\n")
            for _, u := range r.Users {
        fmt.Print("----------------------------------------------------------------\n")
                    fmt.Printf("%s (%s)\n", u.PrimaryEmail, u.Name.FullName)
        fmt.Printf("%s \n", u.CustomSchemas)
                    //fmt.Printf("%s \n", u.group)
                    //fmt.Printf("%s \n", u.group)
                    //fmt.Println(u)
            }
    }
```

tandard attributes (Non-editable)

How could I query ?

Answer (score 2):

The Projection("FULL") has to be Projection("full")

```
        r, err := srv.Users.List().Projection("full"Projection("FULL").).Customer("my_customer"). //MaxResults(20).
            OrderBy("email").Do()
    if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Unable to retrieve users in domain: %v", err)
    }

    if len(r.Users) == 0 {
            fmt.Print("No users found.\n")
    } else {
            fmt.Print("Users:\n")
            for _, u := range r.Users {
        if u.CustomSchemas != nil {
                        fmt.Printf("%s (%s) %s\n", u.PrimaryEmail, u.Name.FullName, u.CustomSchemas)
        }
            }
    }
```